# emmeans pairwise contrasts result in same output values for all?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, paired-data, lsmeans

First of all, I am a beginner at mixed models, so I beg your patience and advice if this post could be improved.

**The structure of the data:**

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   44 obs. of  5 variables:
$ colony   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ condition: Factor w/ 2 levels "filter","pre": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
$ location : Factor w/ 3 levels "AN","AM","AS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ trial    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 ...
$ ninety   : int  3658 616 797 824 580 405 915 476 1445 620 ...
```

There were three ant colonies in the study, and the measurements were repeated on each colony, treatment, and location multiple times (but in the end were unbalanced, some colonies had fewer repeat trials than others). The response variable, "ninety", is in elapsed seconds.

**The mixed-effects model:**
I used the lme4 package in R: `> model <- lmer(log(ninety) ~ condition + location + (1 |colony), data = data, REML = FALSE)`

**Mixed Model output**

```
> summary(finallogninetybuffermodel)
## Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use
##   Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
## Formula: log(ninety) ~ condition + location + (1 | colony)
##    Data: buffer
## 
##      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
##     78.0     88.7    -33.0     66.0       38 
## 
## Scaled residuals: 
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.5606 -0.6441 -0.2184  0.5658  3.3769 
## 
## Random effects:
##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  colony   (Intercept) 0.2360   0.4858  
##  Residual             0.2174   0.4662  
## Number of obs: 44, groups:  colony, 3
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                 Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)       6.0443     0.3093  4.0027  19.539 4.03e-05 ***
## conditionfilter  -0.5491     0.1406 41.1101  -3.906 0.000342 ***
## locationAM        0.3927     0.1699 41.4570   2.312 0.025831 *  
## locationAS        0.2638     0.1844 41.9729   1.431 0.159922    
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Correlation of Fixed Effects:
##             (Intr) cndtnf lctnAM
## conditnfltr -0.227              
## locationAM  -0.230  0.000       
## locationAS  -0.212  0.000  0.455
```

**Emmeans post-hoc pairwise contrasts:**

```
posthoccondloc <- emmeans(finallogninetybuffermodel, lmer.df = 
"satterthwaite", specs = "condition", by = "location")
```

The locations in the summary (below) show different standard errors and confidence limits, but for the pairwise contrasts by location, all the output values, for each location, are the same, but they look different on the bar-arrow plot. Why might that be? I've read everything I could find about lme4 and emmeans online, but I still can't figure it out.

```
> summary(posthoccondloc, adjust = "bonferroni")
## location = AN:
##  condition   emmean        SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
##  pre       6.044318 0.3093493 4.00 4.963388 7.125248
##  filter    5.495213 0.3093493 4.00 4.414283 6.576143
## 
## location = AM:
##  condition   emmean        SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
##  pre       6.436980 0.3168496 4.38 5.377601 7.496360
##  filter    5.887875 0.3168496 4.38 4.828496 6.947255
## 
## location = AS:
##  condition   emmean        SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
##  pre       6.308155 0.3248875 4.81 5.264069 7.352240
##  filter    5.759050 0.3248875 4.81 4.714964 6.803135
## 
## Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
## Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
## Confidence level used: 0.95 
## Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 2 estimates


> contrast(posthoccondloc, pairwise = TRUE, adjust = "bonferroni")
## location = AN:
##  contrast        estimate         SE    df t.ratio p.value
##  pre effect     0.2745525 0.07028776 41.11   3.906  0.0007
##  filter effect -0.2745525 0.07028776 41.11  -3.906  0.0007
## 
## location = AM:
##  contrast        estimate         SE    df t.ratio p.value
##  pre effect     0.2745525 0.07028776 41.11   3.906  0.0007
##  filter effect -0.2745525 0.07028776 41.11  -3.906  0.0007
## 
## location = AS:
##  contrast        estimate         SE    df t.ratio p.value
##  pre effect     0.2745525 0.07028776 41.11   3.906  0.0007
##  filter effect -0.2745525 0.07028776 41.11  -3.906  0.0007
## 
## Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
## P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 2 tests
```

**emmeans Graphs**

```
 > emmip(posthoccondloc, condition ~ location)
```

[image: emmip graph]

```
 > plot(posthoccondloc, comparisons = TRUE)
```

[[image: bar arrow plot of comparisons[2]]

Comment: I am not sure what null hypotheses are corresponding to the p values generated by "contrast(posthoccondloc, pairwise = TRUE, adjust = "bonferroni")". Could you figure them out?

Comment: My null hypothesis was that the "filter" and "pre" conditions would be the same at each location along the trail. As rvl points out below, I should have included the interaction term for condition:location, since that was the case. Thanks for that clarifying question.

Answer (score 4):

You have fitted an additive model - the fixed-effects part is `condition + location`. Therefore you have in fact *specified* that the differences for one factor are exactly the same at each level of the other factor. Since `emmeans()` summarizes a model, then, lo and behold, the results reflect what is specified.

If instead you include the interaction between `condition` and `location` in the model, then the `emmeans()` results will reflect the possibility that factor levels compare differently at levels of the other factor.

I recommend that people think more carefully about the models they are fitting. I think there is a tendency to rush forward without realizing what s crucial thing it is to get the model right.

Comment: rvl - thanks for pointing out my mistake. Your comment has helped me create the model I meant to create, and those results make a lot of sense, given the bad model input I had. I will keep working on examples to work on my model building skills, but thanks for helping me move forward with this one.

Comment: @Russ Lenth , but what if the best model is indeed an additive model? That's my case. I have a very clear lineplot for data in year 1 and Year 2 for two groups which shows almost perfect paralell lines. In addition to it, the anova() output comparing the models also indicates, as suggested, that adding the interaction term does not improve the model. I'm also getting the same results for all contrasts, because it's additive. Is there a way to turn things around in this scenario?

Comment: @LarissaCury Sure, it's fine if the best model is additive. That is not a barrier, in fact, it simplifies things. In particular, you don't need to do "by" comparisons, you can just compare the overall EMMs of `condition` and `location`.